# Simple label "screensaver" help needed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would just like to make the Label's TextColor a random Color each time it enters the screen from left to right, using **arc4random**..

The following code works for 1 random color each time the app loads, but not when it leaves the view!

```
NSTimer* myTimer;

int y = 15;
int x = 0;

-(void)textView
{
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame :CGRectMake(0, 0, 550, 30)];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random()%100/100.0 green:arc4random()%100/100.0 blue:arc4random()%100/100.0 alpha:1];
    myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25];
    myLabel.text = @"My Sample Application";

    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.005 target:self selector:@selector(animatedText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self textView];
    [self animatedText];
}

-(void)animatedText
{
    if ( myLabel.center.x < 640 )
    {
        x += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        y =(arc4random() % 500 ) ;
    }
    myLabel.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour is set in `-(void)textView` - which is only ever called when your view first loads.

Copy `myLabel.textColor = ...` into your `animatedText` method where you reset the x and y position.

Comment: Thank you so much @ev0lution for the quick response and the right answer, it worked!

Comment: No problem, now's a great time to try out the 'tick' button next to my answer. ;)